# Backbone.js factory design pattern implementation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, singleton

I am looking for advice on whether this implementation of the factory design pattern to a Backbone.js collection is a bad implementation.

```
Collections.MyObjects = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Models.MyObject

});

Collections.MyObjects.getInstance = (function(){

    var instances = {},
        defaultName = 'default';

    return function(name)
    {
        name = name || defaultName;

        if (!instances[name])
        {
            instances[name] = new Collections.MyObjects();
        }

        return instances[name];
    };

})();
```

I am looking for alternative implementations and performance optimizations/theories.

Comment: You might want to provide a way to delete instances, otherwise the `instances` object will forever point to every instance generated.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Very good point. In my implementation I actually expect to only use the default name for know, but your point is certainly valid for the implementation. Do you have a suggestion for how this could be cleverly implemented?

Comment: If your code is in a module (requireJS, et al), there'd be no need to privatize the `instances` variable, and you could just operate on it with as many functions as you want.  If not, you could just wrap both (get and delete instance) function definitions in the same closure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative implementation inspired by @numbers1311407's comments to the question.

```
Collections.MyObjects = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Models.MyObject

});

Collections.MyObjects.instance = (function(){

    var instances = {},
        defaultName = 'default';

    return {
        "get": function(name) {
            name = name || defaultName;

            if (!instances[name])
            {
                instances[name] = new Collections.MyObjects();
            }

            return instances[name];
        },
        "delete": function(name) {
            name = name || defaultName;

            if (!instances[name]) return false;

            delete instances[name];
            return true;
        }
    };

})();
```

*Not tested.*